# Adding regex match found in column to last column

Tags: regex, csv, perl, awk, sed

Using perl, sed or awk in bash, I need to find regex patterns in csv column 3 and add it to last column 4.

For example, turn this:

```
2020/10/26,249.00,Test10028
2020/10/24,569.00,Test 00074
2020/10/24,1999.00,0016 1708fqb8ba
2020/10/24,1399.00,00450 165058hb1bda
2020/10/23,399.00,Att-10170 158bb8ba
2020/10/22,599.00,Ref:10150 1605fk0bsf
2020/10/22,5669.00,1605fk0bsf
```

Into this:

```
2020/10/26,249.00,Test10028,10028
2020/10/24,569.00,Test 00074,00074
2020/10/24,1999.00,0016 1708fqb8ba,0016
2020/10/24,1399.00,00450 165058hb1bda,00450
2020/10/23,399.00,Att-10170 158bb8ba,10170
2020/10/22,599.00,Ref:10150 1605fk0bsf,10150
2020/10/22,5669.00,1605fk0bsf,
```

The PCRE regex I found that filters what I need (Only numbers, length 4-5, starts with 0-1, no tailing words.):

```
(?<!\d)[0-1]\d{3,4}(?!\w)
```

[image: RegExr Result]

Using this in akw or sed does not work. Some code I tried:

```
awk -F, 'match($3, /(?<!\d)[0-1]\d{3,4}(?!\d)/, a) {print a[0]","$4 }' file.csv
sed -re 's/(?<!\d)[0-1]\d{3,4}(?!\d)/g' file.csv
```

But perl does give me results using:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!\d)[0-1]\d{3,4}(?!\w)/!!!!/g' file.csv
2020/10/26,249.00,Test!!!!
2020/10/24,569.00,Test !!!!
2020/10/24,!!!!.00,!!!! 1708fqb8ba
2020/10/24,!!!!.00,!!!! 165058hb1bda
2020/10/23,399.00,Att-!!!! 158bb8ba
2020/10/22,599.00,Ref:!!!! 1605fk0bs
```

Comment: awk and sed dont not support pcre.

Comment: In your expected results, is `2020/10/22,5669.00,1605fk0bsf,` OK? Shouldn't it  be `2020/10/22,5669.00,1605fk0bsf,1605`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No trailing words, he said.

Comment: No, no trailing words should be accepted.

Comment: That means, no *letters glued to the number to be extracted* then. But why is the comma added in the result, after `1605fk0bsf`, if there should be no match?

Comment: If no results are found in column 3, only add a comma at the end of line.

Comment: @pynexj  And neither does Perl, hehe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `-F, -a` to cause `@F = split /,/` in order to work with the third field and create a fourth.

```sh
perl -F, -pale'($F[3]) = $F[2] =~ /(?<!\d)([0-1]\d{3,4})(?!\w)/; $_=join(",", @F)'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this GNU awk:

```sh
rx='([^0-9]|^)([01][0-9]{3,4})([^[:alnum:],][^,]*)?$'
awk -v r=$rx 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print ($3 ~ r) ? $0 OFS gensub(r, "\\1\\2\\3,\\2", 1, $3) : $0 OFS}' file.csv > newfile.csv
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/x2Vwhw) (and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MyzEKW/3)).

**Details**

- `([^0-9]|^)`  -  Group 1: any non-digit char or start of string
- `([01][0-9]{3,4})` - Group 2: `0` or `1`, then three or four digits
- `([^[:alnum:],][^,]*)` - an optional sequence of a char other than a digit, letter and comma, and then zero or more chars other than commas.
- `$` - end of string.
- `\1\2\3,\2` - the replacement is the concatenation of Group 1, 2, 3, comma and Group 2 values.

The `awk` command:

- `-v r=$rx`  - passes the regex `$rx` as a variable `r` to awk script
- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` - sets input and output field separator to a comma
- `{print ($3 ~ r) ? $0 OFS gensub(r, "\\1\\2\\3,\\2", 1, $3) : $0 OFS}` - if the regex matches Field 3, the result of `gensub` is appended after a comma to the whole line (record), else only the comma is appended
- `gensub(r, "\\1\\2\\3,\\2", 1, $3)` replaces the first occurrence of the pattern in Field 3.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need gnu-awk to get that done. It's slightly verbose in the regex, but it gets the job done :

```
nice gcat test.csv \
\
| mawk2 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," 
    
  } (($3~/^[^0-9]*[0-1][0-9]                      \
             [0-9][0-9][0-9]?($|[^[:alpha:]])/) && \
                                                    \
    (($++NF=$3)+gsub(/^[^0-9]*|[ ].*$/,"",$NF))) || 1'

2020/10/26,249.00,Test10028,10028
2020/10/24,569.00,Test 00074,00074
2020/10/24,1999.00,0016 1708fqb8ba,0016
2020/10/24,1399.00,00450 165058hb1bda,00450
2020/10/23,399.00,Att-10170 158bb8ba,10170
2020/10/22,599.00,Ref:10150 1605fk0bsf,10150
2020/10/22,5669.00,1605fk0bsf
```

This is purely assuming the input is clean as is, and does not attempt to perform any sort of data cleansing prior to applying the filter.